# Conjecture on odd perfect numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, perfect-numbers

I'm a grad student in mathematics and I've been working with a very gifted high school student (likely the smartest high school student I've ever met) on problems he's brought up and some competition math problems. This student has developed an interest in perfect numbers and the question regarding existence of odd perfect numbers. He has come up with a conjecture about odd perfect numbers, but I have not studied number theory and hence am not necessarily aware of well-known results of the field. So, here we are.

**His idea:**

Suppose $N \in \mathbb{N}$, with prime decomposition $N = p_1^{q_1}\cdots p_n^{q_n}$ Define $\tilde{N} = p_1\cdots p_n$.

*Conjecture:* If $N$ is an odd perfect number, then the sum of reciprocals of all factors of $\tilde{N}$ (excluding 1, including $\tilde{N}$) is less than 1.

> **Q.** Does this conjecture appear to be equivalent to something that has already been established? If this conjecture is true, does it appear to have any obvious implications?

Comment: On how many odd perfect numbers have you guys tested the conjecture? ;)

Comment: On every odd perfect number we could find :)

Comment: The conjecture is equivalent to something that is well-known. If $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum of the divisors of $n$, then the sum of the reciprocals of the divisors of $n$ is $\sigma(n)/n$. (Proof: Exercise.) We have that $n$ is perfect if and only if $\sigma(n) = 2n$, so if $n$ is perfect, the sum of the reciprocals of the divisors of $n$ (including $1$ and $n$ itself) is exactly $2$.

Comment: Does your student claim that the sum is $\le 1$ or $\lt 1$?

Comment: @user8734617 To clarify Jeremy Rouse's comment, $N$ is not square free, by known facts about odd perfect numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers  So $\tilde N | N$, properly.  So the terms in the OP's sum  are a proper subset in the terms in Jeremy's sum.  The OP's sum is $<1$.

Comment: @JeremyRouse - Thanks for your response. I'll parse through this with the student during our next meeting.

Comment: @user8734617 strictly less than one ( < 1 )

Comment: @Stopple Thank you for elaborating.

Comment: Indeed, only two numbers are known to be multiperfect and squarefree, so the posted criterion applies to all perfect numbers that aren't square free.  Gerhard "One Of Them Is Six" Paseman, 2017.12.13.

Answer (score 3):

The earliest result appears to be
$$\frac{1}{2}<\sum_{p\mid N}\frac{1}{p}<2 \log \left (\frac{\pi}{2} \right ),$$

as proved by Perisastri. Other authors have sharpened this result. For example, for a perfect number $N\equiv 0 \mod 3$, the sum has
$$\sum_{p\mid N}\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{3}+ \cdots+\frac{1}{p},$$
see Ribenboim, New Book of Prime Records, [p. 101](https://books.google.com/books?id=2VTSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA101), for a discussion and other references.

Perisastri, M. On the non-existence of odd perfect numbers of a certain form. Math. Student 28 1960 85–86 (1962).  [MR0142494](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0142494).

Comment: Something must be wrong in your identity : $p$ is a dummy variable in the lhs, while it is not in the rhs.

Comment: Here the number $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

The conjecture is true. Since $$\sigma(N)=\prod\left(\frac{p^{e+1}-1}{p-1}\right)$$ and $$\sigma(\tilde{N})=\prod(p+1)$$, it follows that $$\frac{\sigma(N)}{N}=\prod\left(\frac{p^{e+1}-1}{p^e(p-1)}\right)$$ and $$\frac{\sigma(\tilde{N})}{N}=\prod\left(\frac{p+1}{p}\right)$$, so $$\frac{\sigma(\tilde{N})}{\sigma(N)}=\prod\left(\frac{p^{e+2}-p^e}{p^{e+2}-p}\right)\le1$$ with equality iff $N$ is squarefree, where $$N=\prod{p^{e}}$$ and $$N=\prod{p}$$.

All products run over distinct prime factors $p$ of $N$ and $\tilde{N}$ in the equations above.

Since $$\frac{\sigma(N)}{N}=2$$, it follows that $$\frac{\sigma(\tilde{N})}{\tilde{N}}\le2$$ with equality iff $N$ is squarefree. Since $N$ is odd, we have that $\sigma(N)$ isn't divisible by $4$. Since $N$ is squarefree, $$\sigma(N)=\prod(p+1)$$. The product has only even factors, and the product of two or more even integers is divisible by $4$. Hence $N$ is prime and $$2N=N+1$$. This gives $N=1$, a contradiction. Hence $$\frac{\sigma(\tilde{N})}{\tilde{N}}\lt2$$, so $$\frac{\sigma(\tilde{N})}{\tilde{N}}-1\lt1$$, and the desired statement follows.